# `rake db:seed:shop:curtain` fail with “Don't know how to build task 'db:seed:shop:curtain'”?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ruby 2.1.5, rails 4.2, rake

installed gem "seedbank"
seedbank (0.3.0)

I have following structure:
**seeds/shop/curtain/**

I want run all seed files from folder curtain

```
rake db:seed:shop:curtain
```

**rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:seed:shop:curtain'**

What wrong, explain me please. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have following structure: seed/shop/curtain/

As per [**`seedbank documentation`**](https://github.com/james2m/seedbank) the structure should be

```
db/seeds/shop/curtain.seeds.rb
```

So you need to rename `seed` to `seeds`
and add `curtain.seeds.rb` inside `shop` folder so you will get

```
rake db:seed:shop:curtain
```

**EDIT**

Not sure if `seedbank` supports 2-3 level of hierarchy so move the `curtain` folder directly inside `seeds` and try

```
rake db:seed:curtain
```

This will load the seed data from

- `db/seeds.rb`
- `db/seeds/*.seeds.rb`
- `db/seeds/curtain/*.seeds.rb`

Comment: yes, sorry my mistake in question. yes, structure seeds/shop/curtain/

Comment: you don't need `curtain` folder but `curtain.seeds.rb`

Comment: i need, becose in folder shop have anoher seed files, but i need only run files in curtain folder

Comment: yes actually they areallowing to load all seeds in a folder but not sure if they are allowing 2-3 level of hierarchy

Comment: can you try moving out the `curtain` folder in `seeds` folder and try `rake db:seed:curtain`